# How to get the dispatch error as return variable?

Tags: polkadot-js

After transaction is send, it waits till block is included.

The following code though transaction gets successful, it doesn't return the value:

```js
export async function transfer_balance(wsprovider, mnemonic, credit_user, value) {
    const api = await get_api(wsprovider);
    const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });
    const pair = keyring.createFromUri(mnemonic);

    api.tx.balances.transfer(credit_user, value)
        .signAndSend(pair, ({ status, dispatchError }) => {
            if (dispatchError) {
                if (dispatchError.isModule) {
                    const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(dispatchError.asModule);
                    const { docs, name, section } = decoded;
                    return `Error ${section}.${name}: ${docs.join(' ')}`;
                } else {
                    return `Error ${dispatchError.toString()}`;
                }
            } else if (status.isFinalized) {
                return `Finalized ${status.asFinalized.toString()}`;
            }
        })
}
```

How to get the dispatchError and asFinalized as return variable?

I am using the code in wasm.

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use js_sys::Promise;

#[wasm_bindgen(module = "/src/package.js")]
extern "C" {
    #[wasm_bindgen]
    pub fn transfer_balance(wsprovider: String, mnemonic: String, credit_user: String, value: i32) -> String;

}
```

I also tried promises, still it doesn't work.

```js
export function transfer_balance(wsprovider, mnemonic, credit_user, value) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const api = get_api(wsprovider);
        const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });
        const pair = keyring.createFromUri(mnemonic);

        api.tx.balances.transfer(credit_user, value)
            .signAndSend(pair, ({ status, dispatchError }) => {
                if (dispatchError) {
                    if (dispatchError.isModule) {
                        const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(dispatchError.asModule);
                        const { docs, name, section } = decoded;
                        reject(`Error ${section}.${name}: ${docs.join(' ')}`);
                    } else {
                        reject(`Error ${dispatchError.toString()}`);
                    }
                } else if (status.isFinalized) {
                    resolve(`Finalized ${status.asFinalized.toString()}`);
                }
            })
            .catch(reject);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked with following code:

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';
import { Keyring } from '@polkadot/keyring';
import { waitReady } from "@polkadot/wasm-crypto";
export async function transfer_balance(wsprovider, mnemonic, credit_user, value) {
    await waitReady();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const apiPromise = get_api(wsprovider);
        const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });
        const pair = keyring.createFromUri(mnemonic);
         apiPromise.then((api) => {
            api.tx.balances.transfer(credit_user, value)
                .signAndSend(pair, ({ status, dispatchError }) => {
                    if (dispatchError) {
                        if (dispatchError.isModule) {
                            const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(dispatchError.asModule);
                            const { docs, name, section } = decoded;
                            reject(`Error ${section}.${name}: ${docs.join(' ')}`);
                        } else {
                            reject(`Error ${dispatchError.toString()}`);
                        }
                    } else if (status.isFinalized) {
                        resolve(`Finalized ${status.asFinalized.toString()}`);
                    }
                })
                .catch(reject);
        }).catch(reject);
    });
}
```